# Error Sending Emails using PHPMailer over SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I've had a look around as to why my PHP script was not sending any emails when I had the `$mail->isSMTP();` set.

Before I go into the problem, I would like to point out that I am using mailgun.org as my SMTP server. My PHP script is simple, I have an HTML form that forwards data to a PHP file which in turn calls the PHPMailer script and sends an email.

Here is the code to my PHP Script:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
// include 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
// require 'phpmailer/class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
//$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = "smtp.mailgun.org";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Username = ""; //Username removed
$mail->Password = ""; //Password removed
$mail->setFrom('', ''); //Email address and Name removed
$mail->addReplyTo($userMail, $firstName);
$mail->addAddress('emailOne@example.com', 'Name'); //Actual Values Changed
$mail->addAddress('emailTwo@example.com', 'Name'); //Actual Values Changed
$mail->addAddress('emailThree@example.com', 'Name'); //Actual Values Changed
$mail->Subject = 'New Application for website by '. $firstName;
$mail->msgHTML($theMessage);
$mail->AltBody = $theMessage;
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else { //Some HTML code here
}
```

Now then, as you can see, I have commented out the `$mail->isSMTP();` line. This is because whenever I try to use it, the code does not load, and after a long wait gives a 500 error. (Sadly, by cPanel setup does not allow me to view apache logs).

I tried importing just the `class.phpmailer.php` file, but that gave me a fatal error that the class SMTP was not defined, which was expected. I then included the `class.smtp.php` file which gave me the same 500 error.

I had a look around StackOverflow and came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27927181/1854366) however it did not help my case.

I have had a look at Mailgun's logs, but they have no record of the script even trying to connect.

```
Additional Information: If it matters, I have the following files in the same directory:
- sendMail.php //The script above
- class.phpmailer.php
- class.smtp.php
- PHPMailerAutoload.php
- index.html //Not important in this situation.
```

I hope someone will be able to help me out, I'm relying on the non-smtp method for now. :/

Comment: Like that other question says, do the checks that are given in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). It's quite likely your ISP blocks outbound SMTP - are you using GoDaddy?

Comment: @Synchro I've had the same result on both local host and production. However I'll check with the ISP, I'm running a Wordpress installation on the same host and smtp works fine on it, it seems to be something with my code.

Comment: Are you sure? By default, wordpress will be using PHPMailer in isMail() mode. BTW your 500 error sounds like a simple timout as it's unable to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this working fine..!

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
// include 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
// require 'phpmailer/class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->Username = ""; //Username removed
$mail->Password = ""; //Password removed
$mail->addReplyTo($userMail, $firstName);
$mail->SetFrom('emailOne@example.com', 'my name');
$mail->Subject = 'New Application for website by '. $firstName;$mail->MsgHTML($theMessage);
$mail->AddAddress('aswad@yahoo.com', 'my name');
if($mail->Send()) {
    echo "Message sent!";
}else {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```